# In Visual Studio Code can I force the file type for a non-standard file extension?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a buildbot master configuration file:

```
master.cfg
```

The file is a python file. With a python identifier as the first line:

```
# -*- python -*-
```

However VSCode reads it as plain text and I have to manually change it. Is there a way to get VSCode to default this file to have the python type and syntax highlighting?

Comment: when I googled it, it seemed to indicate manual change or use rules based on the filename, which can include a portion of the path.  If that project path contains cfg files which are all python, that would work.

Answer (score 1):

As Kenny Ostrom indicated, VSCode has section on "Adding a file extension to a Language":

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_adding-a-file-extension-to-a-language